# How can I display image in oracle form(6i)

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a question to ask. I have to display same image in same form. Can I add that image in Oracle Form without putting any table or database. Or, How can I display that image. (I'm using Oracle 13.1)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

While in Forms Builder, go to "File" menu, choose "Import - Image", browse for the image and - import it.

Comment: Hi, I checked that before. But I couldn't find that option. Could you give information about oracle forms 6i.

Comment: In Forms 6i, that option is in **File** menu.